# Scope of ComponentOne components change to Private

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, componentone

We are experiencing a weird problem. In our project, our main GUI form implements a ribbon using ComponentOne (C1) controls. Every so often, when editing and saving the form, the scope of some of the C1 components gets changed from "Friend" to "Private." This requires us to go in and do a "change all Private -> Friend" in the .designer document, which I hate doing, but we don't have time to change the scope property of 30 controls every time this happens.

It doesn't happen every time, and it only affects some (~25%) of the C1 controls. We have not seen this problem with any of the native VS2013 controls. It only occurs in the one form, and with only some of the C1 controls.

Any ideas as to why the scope is occasionally getting changed from Friend to Private?

Comment: `Private` is the default for a control on a form, which the VB designer changes to `Friend` (it would stay `private` if you used the C# forms designer). Not sure why the change would be skipped, but you can revert it easily by selecting all controls on the form and changing the `Modifiers` property to `Friend` in the properties grid.

Comment: Apparently there are bugs in the components: http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/modifiers-public-changing/, http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/modifier-behaviour-changes-automatically/.

Comment: Good catch on the C1 groups post. That didn't come up in any of my searches. I posted there... we'll see.